# Why does adding certain numbers such as 3.6 and 3.2 give several "0"s as an output Python

Tags: python

Has anyone come across the problem where you add certain numbers such as 3.2 + 3.6 in python 3 you get an output like "6.800000000000001". This has occurred when I was using Python 3.8. One other set of numbers I added was 2.6 + 2.2 which gave the same result. Does anyone know why this happens, and only on these few numbers?

```
print (3.6 + 3.2)
print (2.6 + 2.2)
```

Comment: This is a fundamental part of floating point numbers

Comment: @Energya Then why does it do this with these numbers when something like 4.3 + 4.4 gives 8.7

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some good info/explanations in [Python docs themselves about floating point arithmetic in computers.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)